# Applescript shell script can't write to file?

Tags: c, macos, shell, applescript, clang

I'm working on an Applescript droplet that will clang any source file I drop on it. 
The only real line I have in it is

```
do shell script "clang " & (POSIX path of this_item as text)
```

However I get the error

`ld can't open output file for writing: a.out, errno=13 for architecture x86_64`

This doesn't happen when I use the Terminal directly, so it's an Applescript problem. How do I get past this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to cd to the folder in question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried..

```
quoted form of (POSIX path of this_item as text)
```

Comment: No that didn't do it. It seems to be accepting the file path just fine, but it's having trouble writing to the output file.

Comment: You should still change the script to quoted form of.

Comment: What does that do, anyway?

Comment: It encloses the file path in single quotes